# JSP / Controller not found for custom component in Hybris addon

Tags: components, sap-commerce-cloud, add-on

I’m running Hybris 6.6 and are building a new addon, that is basically a controller and corresponding JSP. During runtime however, Hybris isn’t finding the controller bean and searches for JSP in the storefront folder (it’s not there, since the JSP is in the storefront addon folder).

I created the addon using extgen, and then installed it in the storefront using also ant.

Steps:

- Created component in -items.xml inheriting from SimpleCMSComponent
- Created controller inheriting from AbstractCMSController,
- Created JSP in addon folder,
- Created component and added to page slot via Imped,
- @Controller has the name equal to component + “Controller”

I’ve debuged the code, and when Hybris tries to find if there is a controller via getBeanFactory().contains(controller) it returns false. If I look at the bean list that the bean factory returns, the bean for the controller is not there.

Any clues on what’s happening? I’ve even tried to create the controller bean explicitly on the -web-spring.xml but doesn’t change anything.

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure

- Your controller should extends `GenericCMSAddOnComponentController` or `AbstractCMSAddOnComponentController` for the compoent inside addon.
- Annotate the Controller with

  `@Controller(YourComponentController)
  @RequestMapping(value="/view/YourComponentController")`
- Add your jsp to `*addon/web/webroot/*/view/*/cms/yourcomponentname.jsp`.
  Refer getView method of AbstractCMSAddOnComponentController for the path
- `*-web-spring.xml` should be in resource folder/path
- component scan should be added for your controller in `*-web-spring.xml`

  `<context:component-scan base-package="my.path.controllers"/>`
- `*-web-spring.xml` should be configured in additionalWebSpringConfigs properties. Refer your addon project.properties

  like
  `myCustomstorefront.additionalWebSpringConfigs.MyAddonName=classpath:/XXX/web/spring/*-web-spring.xml`

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was either the AbstractCMSAddOnController (I was using the normal one) or the component-scan.

Comment: I'm glad this helps you!!

Comment: Both were a cause of your problem.

Comment: I know :) I meant if there was one of them that solved the getBeanFactory problem before I faced the other one :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the excellent instructions by HybrisHelp, it's likely that others coming across this question need to add this to the *-web-spring.xml

```
scope-resolver="de.hybris.platform.spring.IgnoreTenantScopeMetadataResolver"
```

so it looks like

```
<context:component-scan base-package="my.path.controllers" scope-resolver="de.hybris.platform.spring.IgnoreTenantScopeMetadataResolver" />
```

Only with this attribute, the controller was loaded for me.