# Unable to find the Request Map of the overrided controller in hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Hi i have a requirement to override the **acceleratorservices** **SilentOrderPostMockController** to add a new param to the request. I overrided the **SilentOrderPostMockController** in my add-on and changed the url mapping as `sop-mocknew`  to my custom controller. when i fill the payment details the url is being resolved to **https://electronics.local:9002/customstorefront/sop-mocknew/** but it is redirecting it to the hmc instead of going to the controller. I changed the project.properties `sop.post.url` to `/customstorefront/sop-mock/` previously it was `acceleratorservices/sop-mock/`.

Previous url was: **https://electronics.local:9002/acceleratorservices/sop-mock/** this was successfully hitting the OOTB controller.

any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Edit: image has been added
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gy8lF.png)

Comment: I would suggest doing some debug in DefaultPaymentFormActionUrlStrategy#getSopRequestUrl -> that is where the property(i.e sop.post.url) is read and transformed into an URI . Besides from that you said that sop.post.url is /customstorefront/sop-mock/ . Isn't it suppose to be  /customstorefront/sop-mocknew/ ?

Comment: Hi, @dj_frunza i tried giving both /customstorefront/sop-mocknew/  and /customstorefront/sop-mock/ it is redirect me to hmc instead of taking me to my new controller and i debugged DefaultPaymentFormActionUrlStrategy getSopRequestUrl the request url attribute contains the /customstorefront/sop-mocknew/ url

Comment: Can you please provide a picture with the hmc page you are redirected to ?

Comment: Hi @dj_frunza i have added the image, please look into it

Comment: Ok, so you were redirected to hac-> Hybris Administration Console (hmc is something different). Is "storefrontaddon" your storefrontextension ? To me it looks like it is not. Is the Form that is performing the POST sending also the CSRF token ?

Comment: "StoreFrontaddon" is my addon, i saw somewhere in the hybris forums that we can add the dependency of the acceleratorservices and override the controller , that's why i copied the controller to my addon and then override the controller. the post method is sending the csrf token.

Comment: During build the resources(e.g jsps and controllers) are copied into the target extension which should be your storefront. Because of that you should try to access the URL containing the storefront name instead of the addon (i.e https://electronics.local:9002/customstorefront/sop-mock/process ). If you already did that I do not have any ideas left :( . Maybe only putting an exception breakpoint (maybe AccessDeniedException ? ) and try to understand why it is thrown

Comment: @dj_frunza when i add "customstorefront"  to the url it is throwing me server error but the error logs does not contain any exceptions related to the issue

Comment: @dj_frunza so i added the customstorefront once again to check the logs properly, now i got the error saying POST method not supported ant the exception is DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver] Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported]

Comment: I dont know if this helps you, but i found another answer about thsi topic. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52035370/jsp-controller-not-found-for-custom-component-in-hybris-addon/52035785#52035785

Comment: @Mafick it didnt help me.. thanks though

Comment: @ohNo I believe that the error you got ( i.e "Request method 'POST' not supported") shows us progress. So the controller is recognized(otherwise you would have got a 404). In this scenario the cause of the error might be related to the form object that is not initialized properly(This is just an assumption). Since you know the exception you should try to do a little debug in Spring classes to understand why is it thrown